# How to create play and pause in SWF Format?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript

I am beginner to Flash.
I am having a SWF Format, I have to keep that in my html page like a video. I need a play and pause button in that video.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to have playback buttons in HTML or in Flash? Do you have control over Flash content or not? Depending on that the solution can be different.

Answer (score 0):

SWF file is time line based, even if you convert a movie from AVI to SWF generally there is some sort of key frames.your converting program will offer the properties of this inside the software

Easier way to control a SWF movie would be to embed your FLV into the SWF, than add key frames manually. then you can control from a parent SWF with timeline control

If your just playing a movie file in flash , it may be better to use "net-stream" this will allow you to have also full control over the movie file using cue points, this has other advantages  ....quicker loading times, as the whole file would not have to be downloaded first as it allows streaming / Buffering. Using cue points has the same ability as key frames.

so your pause and play button is dependent on how you implement your video